Can a rope thrower act as a propulsion method for land based craft?
Could accelerator devices throwing elastic strings/ropes at the surface (and then pulling them back in) be used to effectively hover over the ground and accelerate by changing the direction of the ropes thrown or the number?
What I imagine is throwing the rope directly at the ground, where it would briefly come to rest/bouncing slightly, before being pulled back up by the other end/both ends if the thrower 'flicks' it like a whip. If the thrown direction is oscillating in the near vertical direction then it would remain stationary (and wasting energy), but the engine would have the potential to keep a group of string spinning at high speed within, whereafter they could be deployed in a near-horizontal direction, allowing for extremely high acceleration of the vehicle, potentially in any direction.
Specifically I'm asking if such a drive could be constructed with near-modern technology, or at all within limits of known materials, and whether it would be powerful enough for it to be built (capable of high acceleration, "all-terrain" movement, structural integrity for at least hundreds of km without maintenance, capacity to hold the power source for itself and some extra weight; efficiency is not a concern outside of the power source being able to push out that much at all; the vehicle is supposed to be autonomous and controlled by an internal computer).
Potential concerns:

Rope material - whether the stresses experienced by the rope would require unrealistically strong materials, as well as the need for its maintenance. I'm imagining some sort of fluid, possibly organic, that binds with itself when under strong external forces. Such a fluid would allow maintenance via filtration, and the impact forces are not a concern, though I have no clue what can be realistically expected regarding possible tensile strength for such quasi-fluids.

Engine structure - whether an engine could realistically reach necessary speeds, contain the forces exerted on it during various modes of operation. Though based on law of equal reaction, I don't think it would be significantly more than what car wheels experience, and unlike those, there's no fear of cutting into the ground.

Ground dust - on one hand the fast rotation of the string should prevent significant dirt from falling onto it, and rest would be flung away during liftoff. On the other hand hard particles could embed into it during impact and then grind the machinery from within. Could this be countered by constantly spraying new layers of material over strings/having strings be very hard and thin?

Power - just how powerful of an engine would be needed for simple hover, relative to the mass of the potential vehicle?

Strings intertwining - unless externally induced, the active controls should be able to prevent that from happening.

Coverable terrain types - I actually do expect it to be able to cover rough terrains and cliffs up to a certain inclination/height. Would the roughness of the terrain unmanageably misdirect strings? Could they be launched with extra force for a jump? Precisely directed into crevices to climb vertical surfaces? A thin and fast string array to drive over water?

Speed, acceleration, weight capacity - Whether it is possible to achieve high enough values that would make such a drive useful.



To be clear, I meant the rope to be a loop (multiple loops for better control, energy/momentum ratio), thrown on one side and pulled on the other. Though the thought of spewing a string and sucking it back up is funny, but I think shouldn't have much of a difference, other than thrower operation.

This is almost certainly, in theory possible, in practice not so much.

Does it have to work on Earth? This would be a pretty cool and quite practical drive in a low-gravity water world. The same propulsion could be used for driving and swimming.

The idea is in theory possible.
A version that technically what is described and possible to build would be very stiff rope and shorter lengths where the vehicle would essentially have wheels without the rims. Linear motors propelling the rope would enable motion.
some real world analogues
A real world similar implementation is tracked vehicles.
Snow chains are more floppy but aren't propelling the vehicle.
so many problems.
A system that uses loose floppy rope? The problems of keeping it from tangling/catching would be very hard.
If using rope that can kink. It will kink eventually, and that will be very bad.
Different height terrain will make balancing hard possibly requiring some excess rope to be in vehicle making another source of tangled rope
fraying, gripping of rope etc.
For the challenge only.
Such a vehicle/propulsion system would only be done for the pure challenge not for any sort of practicality.

To be fair, even "you seat in a hovercraft floating a foot above the ground with a rake in your hands and rake at the ground to move around à la Getting Over It" sounds more plausible than using ropes.

Here's an idea that isn't a rope-thrower, but may be rope-thrower-adjacent. I remember it as one of the proposals for a wheel for the Lunar Rover. I can find nothing to back this up, so just take the idea on its own merits, if it has any.
Suppose you have a wheel with a rubber rim made of overlapping strips of material. At low speeds, the sheets of material lie coiled. Friction and the set of the strips ensures the rim acts as a solid tyre at low speeds. At higher speeds, the strips progressively straighten out under centripetal action, until you eventually have a set of nearly straight strips that support the vehicle by slapping the ground with their tips. This wheel acts as suspension and gearing as the wheel gets larger at speed. When you slow down, the original shape of the strips will wind them back into their original state.
This is a bit like your rope thrower. It is slapping the surface with a non-rigid body to lift the vehicle and push it along, and then hauling in the that body so we can use it again. In this case it is a set of strips rather than a continuous rope.

Yes - you've just reinvented the leg.
The lower limbs of humans and other animals are, shall we say, optimized ropes.  If the animal crawls on its entire body, then the whole body can be considered as a rope.  Just ask Indiana Jones!  By throwing our legs at the ground and letting them rebound back at us, we can move along reasonably well.

Strictly speaking, legs aren't ropes, because they have bones, or at least rigid parts of other origin. However this answer counts as a funny one.

I doubt it, assuming I have understood the layout you have in mind, but something similar is possible. The material and engineering challenges aren't overwhelmingly problematic I can think of several options that would work, the energy equation isn't on your side if the motion is purely vertical though. The workable alternative is something like a skipping rope where the rotation of a cable at a set tension striking the ground propels the vehicle upwards and forward. Such a system is likely to be quite heavy but possibly not prohibitively so, you're effectively replacing the tyres on something that could otherwise be a fairly standard all terrain vehicle. Such a system will only work at a very high rate of rotation, at lower speeds, such as when starting and stopping, the vehicle will shake abominably. Also you need landing struts that raise the vehicle off the ground, creating space for the cable(s) to start rotating.

No, this will not work
If a vehicle throws reaction mass away then the same force that was used to throw it will operate on the vehicle in the opposite direction - this is how rocket engines work.  However, as soon as the reaction mass is retracted/rebounds by virtue of being attached by a tether then it reverses the propulsive force, giving a net movement of zero.  If it were possible to throw reaction mass away and then retrieve it without losing the energy gained by throwing it away in the first place then space travel would not be limited by the tyranny of the rocket equation.
Note that it does not matter how advanced the materials used for the "strings" are or the sophistication of the motors that manipulate them, basic physics prevent this concept from ever working.
(The title suggested to me that this was an idea for throwing out grappling hooks and then retracting them to pull a craft along the ground - that would probably be an extremely impractical method of propulsion, but it could work on the correct ground type.)

I don't think this argument is sound. If you were throwing the rope in free space and then hauling it back, yes, you'd need to apply the same impulse in reversing its outward motion as you applied to launch it in the first place, and would get no propulsion. It's not in free space though, it's being stopped by the ground and all you're doing is hauling it back up against gravity. It's not really any different from a hovercraft, just with the rope instead of a fluid.

And apart from all the other issues, it'd probably behave like a hovercraft using narrow jets...digging into the ground, blasting dirt and debris all over the place, being very messily lethal if anyone got too close...

@ChristopherJamesHuff the ground interactions won't move the vehicle because the strings are not rigid.  If they were rigid then they would act like legs - they'd still blast holes in the ground and spray dirt everywhere, as you correctly identify, but the impact with the ground would provide an upwards force on the vehicle.  The hovercraft analogy doesn't apply here because a hovercraft isn't recirculating the same air that it blasts out from its skirts - if it did suck back up all the air it blasts out then it would not be a working hovercraft.

No, the ground interactions have no effect on the vehicle. They will stop the ropes, however. The vehicle's no longer decelerating a rope on an outward trajectory, it's picking it up off the ground. And a hovercraft will still hover just fine if you put it in an enclosed area so it does recirculate the air.

I think Christopher is right here—the argument in this answer is not valid and the method theoretically could work. Throwing a rope at the ground will transfer downward momentum into the rope, and then into the ground; the net effect of this is an upward force. Retracting the rope will transfer upward momentum into the rope, but then recover it again; the net effect of this is no force. The combination of the two effects (an upward force and no force) is an upward force.

Or, a simpler argument: throwing ropes at the ground will certainly exert a downward force on the ground, so by Newton's third law, it must exert an upward force on the vehicle (considering the ropes as part of the vehicle). All that's needed is to throw the ropes so that they hit the ground very hard, very frequently.

Or consider a wheel consisting of a flexible hoop supported by a spinning loop of "rope" inside. Apart from gyroscopic forces and the fact that the vehicle's sitting on top of the wheel rather than attached via a hub, it'll just act like a rigid wheel, despite neither component being capable of directly transmitting forces.

@Sophie If the rope is flexible, then how does the force at the tip of the rope transmit to a force at the top of the rope (where it is attached to the vehicle.)

@KerrAvon2055  We would have a potential force imbalance (as described by the OP) due to the ropes being thrown out fast, and pulled in slowly. Since all friction increases with speed-squared, throwing a rope at speed would require greater friction to be overcome than pulling it back in slowly, which looks to me like more force.

@MikeB Well, when the rope is being tossed out initially, presumably it's bunched up or coiled, so the entire rope is under compression and exerts an upward force on the vehicle body. When the rope hits the ground, this, of course, does not produce any force on the vehicle body. When the rope starts to be pulled in again, it's under tension and produces a downward force on the vehicle body (I'm pretty sure this doesn't need any explanation). Finally, when the rope finishes being pulled in, it exerts an upward force again.

It just occurred to me that I'm neglecting the weight of the rope in my arguments. But that can be pulled out and considered separately. So the forces are (1) upward force from tossing the rope, (2) downward force from accelerating the rope to retract it, (3) upward force from decelerating the rope after retracting it, and (4) the combined weight of the ropes and vehicle body. Forces (2) and (3) cancel each other out, so all that's needed is for force (1) to be greater than force (4).

I don't think it's quite so simple, @SophieSwett.  Depending on exactly how the rope unrolls / decompresses / whatever, it is likely that some of the force decelerating it comes from tension against the vehicle.  This would be the case for the whip-like flick the OP describes, for example.  That adds more downward force, scaling with the rope's initial acceleration toward the ground.  If the rope's mass is relatively evenly distributed, and only its tip reaches the ground, then most of the upward force on the vehicle will be countered by downward force from this tension.

That doesn't mean that this mode of locomotion is necessarily impossible in principle, but my estimate is that it is altogether impractical, and I'm doubtful that it is possible with materials and energy technologies remotely similar to those we have today.

@JohnBollinger just need to make it lighter, not less massive. Put a hot air balloon on it to make it close to weightless and it would work fine. A long pole with a hook on the end would be better in every way, but it would work.

@gs, as described in the question, two different sets of ropes serve the purpose on one hand of keeping the vehicle suspended, and on the other hand of producing lateral movement. Replacing most or all of the vertical suspension aspect with a balloon would probably be more feasible, but it doesn't seem to be what the question is asking for.  Note especially that the question imagines rapid lateral movement, which would be inhibited by a balloon.

I imagine rope to be a loop, so most of it would touch ground over time, thus most of the impulse of the rope would be reflected from it. The mass of the rope is a positive until a certain point, as it increases impulse per energy. Active support structures are the inspiration, except the mass is unsheathed, so along with pushing up, at higher speeds/smaller lengths, the rope would be more circular, and more parallel to the ground at points of contact, so more of momentum transfered would be horizontal. However its less efficient for support as ground can't reflect the impulse as sheath can.

I also see it best implemented as a loop. No need to alternate between launching and retrieval stages. As far as materials and energy goes, you could probably get it to basically work at the scale of a quadcopter, with similar hardware and similar operation times. Big lipo battery, a couple brushless motors, a couple bicycle chains or rubber belts for the wheels, a stabilizing tail that drags on the ground...and basically no carrying capacity, limited directional control, and a rather high minimum speed.

I believe this is theoretically possible.
If a vehicle hovering above ground level is carrying a Mass on a wire. It would be able to 'throw' the mass downwards with as much force as its motor and energy source permitted.
The more energy the mass was thrown downwards with, the greater the upward force on the vehicle.
However, because it would be the ground and not vehicle arresting the motion of the mass. The upward motion is essentially free.
There is still the downward force from the weight of the vehicle and the extra downward force required to hoist the mass back into the vehicle so it could be used again for the next 'fling', but both of those forces would always be the same whereas the upward force generated from flinging the mass downwards is essentially unlimited (given the perfect energy source and motor)

It would rip itself to pieces. We don't know of any materials that would handle such abuse long term. It seems doubtful that you could achieve constant acceleration as it would depend on the ground composition. Uneven terrain would be unmanageable for any length of time.
So, in answer to the question.... no.

Materials aside, any single rope throw would only deliver as much momentum to the system, but pulling the rope back would take too long for that momentum to matter. Also such strikes would rend the terrain asunder, potentially letting small bits of stone/sand into its systems to add damage to more damage. A hovercraft is the thing that's somewhat similar to this idea, but it doesn't pull air from below, making it hover on an air cushion; this one would not be able to even lift off the ground, unless the ropes would be replaced with legs.
